# Access 2003 SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am **new** with access 2003 and been stuck on this query I have wrote for a while now. The tables and column names, operators and brackets i believe are all correct however I am getting a syntax error only after I inserted the following join operation

```
FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tLEDGERS ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
INNER JOIN (tProjects
```

below is my full code

```
SELECT DISTINCT tProjects.CC_IO AS ProjectNo,
Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")" AS [Line/Item/Text],
tUsers.LastName AS Last_Name, 
tDailyEntries.UserId AS UserID, 
contractordailyrate AS DailyRate, 
contractordailyhours AS Hours, 
ROUND(contractordailyrate / contractordailyhours, 2) AS HourlyRate,
ROUND(SUM(tDailyEntries.CalculatedDailyHours), 2) AS MonthlyHours, 
ROUND((HourlyRate * MonthlyHours), 2) AS Charge, 
ROUND(Charge+ROUND((Charge*0.2),2),2) AS Accruals, tProjects.Project AS Project
FROM (tDailyEntries
INNER JOIN tLEDGERS ON tLEDGERS.Action = tDailyEntries.ActionNo)
INNER JOIN (tProjects 
RIGHT JOIN (textcontractor 
RIGHT JOIN (tTitle 
RIGHT JOIN ((Location 
RIGHT JOIN (tDepartments 
RIGHT JOIN tUsers 
ON tProjectType.ProjectTypeID = tProjects.ProjectTypeID)
ON tDepartments.DeptID = tUsers.DeptID) 
ON tLocation.LocationID = tUsers.LocationID) 
RIGHT JOIN (((tDailyEntries 
LEFT JOIN tDepartments AS tDepartments_1 
ON tDailyEntries.DeptCharged = tDepartments_1.DeptShortName) 
LEFT JOIN tActions ON tDailyEntries.ActionNo = tActions.ActionID) 
LEFT JOIN tLookups 
ON tDailyEntries.Zone = tLookups.LookupID) 
ON tUsers.UserID = tDailyEntries.UserID) 
LEFT JOIN textmain 
ON tUsers.UserID = textmain.userID) 
ON tTitle.TitleID = tUsers.TitleID) 
ON textcontractor.companyid = textmain.contractorcompany) 
ON tProjects.ProjectID = tDailyEntries.ProjectNo
WHERE tTitle.TitleID = 37 
AND Month([DateFrom]) = MonthNum 
AND Day([DateFrom]) <21
GROUP BY tProjects.CC_IO, Year([DateFrom]) & " Accrual " & MonthName(Month([DateFrom])) & " - "+[CompanyName] & " ( "+([LastName]) & ")", tUsers.LastName, tDailyEntries.UserId, textmain.contractordailyrate, 
Month([DateFrom]), textmain.contractordailyhours, tProjects.Project;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What does the tProjects table joins on?

Comment: tProjects joins ON to ON tProjectType.ProjectTypeID = tProjects.ProjectTypeID)